# Postgresql on Mac OS X with ICU patch

Tags: macos, postgresql, icu

Has anyone built Postgresql on Mac OS X with Palle Girgensohn's ICU patch? If so, what problems did you encounter, and did was the change in collation behavior satisfactory?

I am working with Postgresql 9.2 and Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8.

Comment: Google suggests that the patch in question is from 2005. There's about zero chance of it applying cleanly to PostgreSQL 9.2. A lot of work is likely to be necessary to update it unless someone's been forward-porting the work to new releases. Links and details please.

Answer (score 3):

Google suggests that the patch in question is from 2005. There's about zero chance of it applying cleanly to PostgreSQL 9.2. A lot of work is likely to be necessary to update it unless someone's been forward-porting the work to new releases.

You haven't defined what's unsatisfactory to you about the current collation behaviour - though frankly, given Mac OS X's libc I imagine the answer is "a lot". I don't think you have a great many options at this point unless you're willing to undertake the effort to forward-port the ICU patch.

I'd really love to see PostgreSQL able to support ICU collation, and it's on my list of things to work on if I can ever find the time to do that kind of nobody-will-fund-this work. Implementing it isn't so much the challenge as convincing the team to accept the change, though, and assuaging or working around any performance concerns.

Personally I'd just run it on Linux, where the saner collation and encoding support would help a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, [patch](http://people.freebsd.org/~girgen/postgresql-icu/README.html) is available for PostgreSQL up to version 9.1. I haven't tested it yet, but I think patch itself works fine since it is quite small and, AFAIK, it is used under FreeBSD by default. Since Mac OS X is compatible with GNU autoconf, patch should work from the box.

Having some proficiency in C, you can try to upgrade it to PostgreSQL 9.2 or 9.3 by yourself.
Also, 1C provides [patches for using PostgreSQL with their 1C:Enterprise platform](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/postgres_patches_notes.htm). These patches also provide ICU library, and there are versions for PostgreSQL both 9.1 and 9.2. You can take a look and get some ideas about upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible - I have just finished the process based off a MacPorts installation (currently version 9.3.5 of PostgreSQL). I used the 9.2.8 patchfile from [Palle's patch page](http://people.freebsd.org/~girgen/postgresql-icu/), modified slightly refer to the 9.3.5 soruce base and use version 2.63 of autoconf instead of 2.69, then used the `Portfile` modifications from [this MacPorts ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33145) to tell MacPorts how to apply the patch file.

Results from my preliminary testing are mostly fine, e.g.

```
postgres=# show server_encoding;
 client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from comments order by comment;
 comment 
---------
 gros
 gross
 groß
 grot
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from comments order by comment collate "C";
 comment 
---------
 gros
 gross
 grot
 groß
(4 rows)

postgres=# select upper('ß');
 upper 
-------
 SS
(1 row)
```

But note ...

```
postgres=# select upper('ß') collate "C";
 upper 
-------
 SS
(1 row)
```

(I would have expected just 'ß'.)